# What is the default order from a has_many relationship in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What is the default order from a has_many relationship in Rails?

Thought that in the `ActiveRecord:Base` the `default_scope` was `order: 'created_at ASC`', but I had to specify to get it ordering properly.

I have looked in the docs and in the source code, but I could not find any reference on that!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no order specified by default, so they will be ordered by how the database returns them. Usually this is by ID or insert order. The created_at column is only there if you specify it in your migrations so it wouldn't make sense for that to be the default order column.

Comment: Nice, i just had realized that, with fes tests today!